# How to stop TempData persisting sometimes.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Given a controller action such as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel model)
{
       model.Process();
       return RedirectResult("/somepage");
}
```

I want to alter it to return JSon on occasion, dependent on a condition:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel model)
{
       model.Process();
       if (model.ReturnJson)
       {
             return Json(model);
       }

       return Redirect("/somepage");
}
```

However, `Process()` sets tempdata which breaks things on the future page impressions. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TempData.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.clear(v=vs.118).aspx) to get rid of all of it, or [`TempData.Remove(“YourKey”)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.remove%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to be selective if there is something in there you do need.

E.g.

```
   if (model.ReturnJson)
   {
         TempData.Clear();
         return Json(model);
   }
```

---

Tho for clarity you may want two different `Action`s, as your first example seems to implement [P-R-G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and it seems to me you're "muddying the water" by trying to add something in to make one `Action` do two things, for not much code reuse.